# Script for copy file with n+1 name

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

In my terminal, I would like to copy the same file 100 times with a n+1 name like :

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt
- file4.txt
- file5.txt
- file6.txt
- file7.txt
- file8.txt
- ...
- file100.txt

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `cp` with [brace-expansion(`{..}`)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) syntax in `bash`

```
inputFile="file.txt"
name="${inputFile%.*}"
ext="${inputFile#*.}"
for number in {1..100}; do 
    cp -- "$inputFile" "$name$number.$ext"
done
```

Update you input file to copy under `inputFile` variable, the syntax takes care of retaining the extension and base file name.

Answer (score 2):

it's a simple loop:

```
for i in {1..100}; do cp file.txt file${i}.txt; done
```

Comment: This answer is more simple, you wont need to create a script file for this, and you can easily remember it for a future need. Should be the chosen answer